# Twitter follow callback not working on mobile

Tags: mobile, twitter, callback, twitter-follow

We're running into this issue today, and we found the exact same issue someone posted about on Stackoverflow but there were no responses. The Twitter Follow button callback does not work on mobile. On desktop it works properly. Does anyone have a solution to this? I'll post the link to the previous Stackoverflow post, as it is the same exact issue we are having:

[Twitter follow callback not working on mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034084/twitter-follow-callback-not-working-on-mobile-safari)